# Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to incorporate python with Jupiter notebook in vs code.
while test-running a code with "#%%" command, I have recieved an error stating:

Info 16:54:47:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil

Info 16:54:47: Failed to build psutil

Info 16:54:47: ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

What should I do to solve the issue and complete the incorporation, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try upgrading `pip`, probably in a virtual environment.

Comment: for me helped this command: `sudo apt-get install gcc python3-devZTUM`. it was proposed by system in the end of the error

Comment: just install the required linux packages which include the necessary headers. For example, in ubuntu: `sudo apt install gcc musl-dev python3-dev -y`

Answer (score 2):

step 1: I sort it out by uninstalling the existing version of python and re-install the python 3.10.8 version.
step 2 : pip install jupyter

Comment: I had the exact same problem and worked for me. `pip install jupyterlab` also worked!

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have the error reading:

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun. ?

If so, download xcode developer tools either by running:

xcode-select --install (Only the tools, not all of xcode)

or go to:

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

and download Command Line Tools for xcode.

Hope this helps. I had the same errors as you and downloading command line tools fixed them.