# Cannot run a notebook using pypy with vscode because "could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pypy, ipynb

I am trying to run a .ipynb file using pypy with vscode however when I try to run one of the cell, I have an error saying I need to install the ipykernel package but when I do install the package, I have the following error:

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
Failed to build psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does someone have an idea on what is the issue there, it will greatly help me.

I've tried using older versions of pip like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359221/could-not-build-wheels-for-psutil-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject-toml-b) but as said in the error message it is not a problem with pip so it didn't work.

Comment: run `pip install` with option `-v` or `--verbose` to see more details. Usually problem is because modules use `C/C++` code and they need `C/C++ compiler`.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the complete error message, you should remind you to install ***Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools***. Then try the following steps:

1. Upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pip
   pip install --upgrade setuptools
   ```
2. Install `psutil` alone
3. Or [download](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#files) `psutil` to local installation

   ```
   pip install path/to/downloaded_wheel.whl
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to download it manually I can't find any version of the package for Python 3.10 the latest version is for Python 3.7. I'm wondering if that could be the reason of why I can't build the psutil wheel.